# Instrument all GETSTATIC and PUTSTATIC bytecode instructions

Tags: java, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javassist

I need to instrument all `getstatic` and `putstatic` bytecode instructions within some classes. 
I know the basics of Java Agents, what I'm looking for is a framework that allows to add the instrumentation code at source level. So I want to instrument the instruction with plain java code and not handwritten bytecode.
I've seen that Javassist has this feature, but not for bytecode level instrumentation.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just wondering: what is the problem you intend to solve?

Comment: I'm implementing a data-flow analysis of the static program state

Comment: How do you imagine how “to add the instrumentation code at source level” should work with “bytecode level instrumentation”? I guess, your actual problem is much simpler to solve. Instrument the instructions by injecting a simple method invocation. The implementation of the invoked method can be done with plain Java source code.

Comment: The problem is that I need access to the arguments of put and getstatic because I need to log them. This requires things like duplicating the top of the stack. I was hoping for some high level api that offers direct access to the argument (the value that is pushed to the stack / removed from it) for a certain bytecode instruction.

Comment: A “high-level API” is not the same as a “source level API”. But there is no higher level pendant to the “value on the stack” concept and it’s not necessary anyway. For `getstatic`, there is no argument on the stack. For `putstatic`, there is a value on the stack matching the field’s type, but all you have to care for, is, whether it is a “type 2” (`long` or `double`) or “type 1” (everything else), when duplicating the entry.

Answer (score 0):

In Javassist, this is a bit tedious. Basically, what you need to to is to iterate over the code of a method:

```
ClassPool classPool = ...
for (Object method : managedCtClass.getClassFile().getMethods()) {
  MethodInfo methodInfo = (MethodInfo) oMethod;
  if (methodInfo.getCodeAttribute() == null) {
    continue;
  }
  CodeIterator iterator = methodInfo.getCodeAttribute().iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    int index = iterator.next();
    int opcode = iterator.byteAt(index);
    if (opcode != Opcode.PUTFIELD && opcode != Opcode.GETFIELD) {
      continue;
    }
    // manually adjust the byte code by itr.writeXXX methods.
  }
  methodInfo.getCodeAttribute().setAttribute(MapMaker.make(classPool, methodInfo));
}
```

Make sure that once you change byte code, you need to replace the attribute after completing the iteration over all code elements.

Comment: Actually it's much easier if done with the visitor API. Also this is not what I asked for. I asked for a higher level, so that I don't have to manually write the bytecode